# Can't refer to Django templates

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, directory-structure

Below is my directories created by using Django

isap/users needs to get templates from isap/isap/templates/users/login.html

```
isap/
 L isap
    L templates
        L users
            L login.html
    L ....
        L ....
            L .....
 L ...
 L users
    L views.py
    L urls.py
```

So, I added `TEMPLATE = [{..., "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASEDIR2, "templates/")],APP_DIRS=True,....}]`in `settings.py` and `BASEDIR2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + '\\isap'`

Also, I already added the apps

```
PROJECT_APPS = [isap.apps.IsapConfig, users.apps.UsersConfig, ...]
```

But, the 404(Page not found) error is generated.

below is my users/views.py

```
import os
import requests
from django.utils import translation
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from django.views.generic import FormView, DetailView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from . import forms, models, mixins


class LoginView(mixins.LoggedOutOnlyView, FormView):
    template_name = "users/login.html"
    form_class = forms.LoginForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(self.request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        next_arg = self.request.GET.get("next")
        if next_arg is not None:
            return next_arg
        else:
            return reverse("core:home")
```

How can I link the templates to isap/users/views.py?

Answer (score 0):

The setting is called `TEMPLATES`, plural but your post says `TEMPLATE`

Comment: Unpositioned django template error. Resolution complete